# Why is boolean DBHelper.updateStudents(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String, java.lang.String)on nullobjectreference

Tags: android, database, string, sqlite, nullreferenceexception

I have an activity which gets data of user from SQLite database and displays in edittexts allowing user to make changes to his info. When chnges are made, the Db.update function is called. I am getting this error.

```
btnSave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String user = fullname.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String email_id = email.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String phone = number.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String countrycode = ccp.getSelectedCountryCode();
                String pass = password.getEditText().getText().toString();
                String ve_pass = verifypassword.getEditText().getText().toString();
                Toast.makeText(user_info.this, user+email_id+phone, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                if (user.equals("") || pass.equals("") || ve_pass.equals("") || email_id.equals("") || (phone.equals("")))
                    Toast.makeText(user_info.this, "Please enter all the fields", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                else {
                    if (pass.equals(ve_pass)) {

                        Boolean update = DB.updateStudents(user, email_id, countrycode, phone, pass);
                        if ( update== true)
                        {
                            Toast.makeText(user_info.this, "updated successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), add_device.class);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
```

This is the logcat

```
2021-06-16 14:55:46.380 18829-18829/nanodevlab.screens E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: nanodevlab.screens, PID: 18829
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean nanodevlab.screens.DBHelper.updateStudents(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at nanodevlab.screens.user_info$1.onClick(user_info.java:81)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6256)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:24701)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

The values in Strings are not null, I have checked them individually.

This is my update function in DBHELPER class

```
public boolean updateStudents(String username, String email, String countrycode, String number, String password){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues= new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("username", username);
        contentValues.put("email", email);
        contentValues.put("countrycode", countrycode);
        contentValues.put("number", number);
        contentValues.put("password", password);

        db.update(TABLE_USER, contentValues, email + " = ? " ,
                new String[]{String.valueOf(email)});

        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It means that your `DB` variable is not initialized. You should initialize your `DB` variable before you will invoke some calls:

```
DB = new DbHelper(); // or something like this
Boolean update = DB.updateStudents(user, email_id, countrycode, phone, pass);
```

Comment: It was initialized before the button event listener. Still is not working.